# How to read the content of Infinispan Cache

Tags: java, jboss, infinispan

I use Infinispan Cache in my Java project.
How I can read content of Infinispan Cache?
I searched the external libraries, but unsuccessfully.

I want to open something on the browser and look at the contents, objects, current usage in RAM (it would not be bad), expired / not expired, what time expired for each and how many of them in the system.

This can be done for example via jvisualvm, but this is not convenient, and there is a connection problem. And there is no web-interface for jvisualvm.

There are exists something for solve this question?

Comment: Please clarify, what do you mean by "reading content"? And what are those "external libraries"? Iterating through all entries? Cache API inherits from ConcurrentMap, and the keySet(), entrySet() and values() methods work as expected.
Maybe you use it as Hibernate ORM Second Level Cache, or through Spring?

Comment: I want to open something on the browser and look at the contents, objects, current usage in RAM (it would not be bad), expired / not expired, what time expired for each and how many of them in the system.

This can be done for example via jvisualvm, but this is not convenient, and there is a connection problem. And there is no for jvisualvm.

Comment: Supplemented the question above

Answer (score 0):

As you've noticed, some stat or available operationes are exposed through JMX. For a better user experience, there's the [Infinispan Console](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-management-console) but this integrates with infinispan running as Server, not in embedded mode (afaik).